# How can writing to a shared array (over a pointer) in a nested for loop parallelized with OpenMP produce wrong results?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a very strange problem that I'm try to solve and understand. I have a nested for loop of the following form:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided) shared(Array) collapse(3)
for (int i=istart; i<iend; i++)
{
  for (int j=jstart; j<jend; j++)
  {
    for(int k=kstart; k<kend; k++)
    {
       Int IJK = (i*(jend-jstart) + (j-jstart))*(kend-kstart) + (k-kstart);
       Array[3*IJK + 2] = an operation with some shared values;
    }
  }
}
```

There are three loops of this form, with `Array[3*IJK]`, `Array[3*IJK + 1]` and `Array[3*IJK+2]` respectively. Array is also actually a shared pointer and for the value of `IJK`, a function is actually called (inlined).

I first tried parallelizing all loops and the program runs through, but the results are different compared to my serial results.

Now come the strange parts.

The for loop that is of this same structure, but has `Array[3*IJK + 1]` instead, produces correct results when it is parallelized (the other loops are serial in this case). But as soon as I parallelize one of the other loops, I get different results. It is only this single loop that produces correct results when parallelized by itself.

Also, If I don't use `collapse`, or `collapse(2)` instead of `collapse(3)`, I get different results. Only with the `#pragma` statement as above, I get correct results in the `Array[3*IJK + 1]` loop.

I thought it might have something to do with the order in which `Array` was written to, but with an ordered clause and construct, I still get wrong results.

What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your serial case is correct?

Your `IJK` calculation makes no sense to me; for one thing, it doesn't depend on `j` at all.   As it is, if two threads get the same (i,k) pair with different j -- certainly possible with `collapse(3)` -- there's going to be a race condition as they both will be trying to write to the same IJK.

Are you sure you don't want something like

```
   Int IJK = (i*(jend-jstart) + (j-jstart))*(kend-kstart) + (k-kstart);
```

?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I copied my IJK calculation incorrectly. I tried to rewrite the original code with shorter variables and ended up copying the wrong thing. In the actual code the IJK calculation is correct.

Comment: Ok so I've checked and double checked again. The serial case is correct, and the IJKs are definitely unique. I find it very strange that it works for collapse(3), but not for collapse(2). Can't seem to find a solution for the Array[IJK*3+2]. I tried with num_threads(1) and it also leads to different results...